# Formating the Line Chart in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am new to c# programming and creating my first Windows forms application. I have a two 1-D Arrays, one represents the X Axis Values and the other represents Y axis.

I am trying to create a graph from them using the following code.

```
public void drawgraph()
    {
        chart1.Series["Series1"].Name = MemsName;
        for (int i = 0; i < VmicArray.Length; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series[MemsName].Points.AddXY(VmicArray[i], SensitivityArray[i]);

        }

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Vmic Value";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Sensitivity";
    }
```

I am getting the XAxis values which I have in Array(like -2.333333754 or 6.46870) with the interval of 5 which I have set. The range of X axis is have is from -4 to +8.

Is there anyone who can help me in getting a ouput like we get in Excel Graphs? I am trying for Long time always I mess up with the values of X axis.

I Need the graph with XAxis value from -10 to +10 with the interval of 1 and mapping the Y values to corresponding X values on graph.

Unfortunately I am not able to post any Images :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to project a certain range of values to another range you need to use linear interpolation between the values. First determine the old min and max values (`MinX` and `MaxX`) and define the new limits (-10, 10).

Then use a simple formula to determine the new x value of an arbitrary old value.

```
double MinX = VmicArray.min;
double MaxX = VmicArray.Max;

double NewMin = -10;
double NewMax = 10;

for (i = 0; i <= VmicArray.Count - 1; i++) {
    // Linear interpolation     
    double NewX = VmicArray(i) / (MaxX - MinX) * (NewMax - NewMin) + NewMin;
}
```

Recalculate each X value before you use `AddXY`.

---

In order to just change the visible bounds of each axis you can use the `XAxis.Minimum` and `XAxis.Maximum` as well as the `XAxis.Interval` properties:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = -10;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Jens, your code just gave me the thought that my all data is in string. I just converted them to double before plotting and all Looks good when I set Minimum and Maximum.

Comment: Oh, yes using string data is the wrong way. Glad that it works now.